# How do I change my code, so that I don't have to use "break"?

Tags: java, break

I'm completing an assignment give to me by my professor, and it states that I can't use break in my code, but without ***break*** the code doesn't stop when it needs to. I tried a couple of different options that I found on the internet, but nothing worked. This is my code:

```
while (x >= 0 && x <= 11 && y >= 0 || x >= 11 && x <= 22 && y >= -7) {
        x = v0 * t*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
        y = v0 * t*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a)) - g * (t*t) / 2;
        System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
        if (x <= 20 && x >= 17 && y <= -2 && y >= -7) {
            hitTarget = true;
            break;
        }
    t += 0.05;
    }
```

Comment: Set a flag or put it in a method you can return from instead.

Comment: Professors, stop doing this to your students; there is actual research showing that it's easier for humans to understand code using `break` compared to code which uses a boolean flag to achieve the same effect. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2989026.2950065

Comment: @kaya3 That said, it's difficult for me (who have been using Java _since 1.1_) to always immediately identify the point to which the break passes control. Refactoring to a method with an early return is nearly always cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `!hitTarget` in `while`. Since you're setting `hitTarget = true` when that condition gets satisfied, the loop will stop

```
while (!hitTarget && x >= 0 && x <= 11 && y >= 0 || x >= 11 && x <= 22 && y >= -7) {
    //..
}
```

[Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

> !       Logical complement operator;
> inverts the value of a boolean

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know I had to use a "!", without it it didn't work.

Comment: Check the edited answer about logical NOT operator.

Comment: Probably does not matter, but unless OP does if(!hitTarget) t += 0.05;. this will not be semantically the same

Comment: @dreamcrash right. I believe the OP will have figured that out.

Comment: @shb Yes, I agree no need to change your answer, the //.. might imply that change as well